# jersey-client version mismatch in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, jersey-client

For creating a REST Client am using the below dependency in Spring Boot:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Which in turn downloads the jersey-client-2.23.1.jar. 
My code for request builder is as below:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget targetUrl = client.target("Some URL").path(userid)
            .path("Some String");
Builder requestBuilder = targetUrl.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonArray objArray = (JsonArray) parser.parse(requestBuilder.get(String.class));
```

However I am getting the below exception in line number 3 of the above code:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap.addAll(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.accept(ClientRequest.java:336) ~[jersey-client-2.23.1.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.request(JerseyWebTarget.java:221) ~[jersey-client-2.23.1.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.request(JerseyWebTarget.java:59) ~[jersey-client-2.23.1.jar:na]
```

I saw few solution that it is due to version mismatch. So, I tried to added a lower version dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

But spring boot is not considering this version of jersey-client. Is there any way out so that I can solve the issue?

**EDIT 1:**
As mentioned in the first answer I used mvn dependency:tree and found 2 different version of jersey client available. One is compile time and one is run time:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.23.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.23.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.23.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.23.1:compile
```

and

```
[INFO] +- some.project.specific:jar:1.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- some.project.specific:jar:1.4.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.19.1:runtime
```

I tried to exclude version 2.23.1 as below. Still it is including the jar.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-client-2.23.1</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: what is the application server ? is it JEE container or normal web server ?

Comment: Spring boot. Running as microservice.

Answer (score 0):

Check other dependencies on your project, try running `mvn dependency:tree`. Probably you have some other dependency to jersey 1.XX version, you should exclude it to keep just the 2.23.1.

Comment: I have edited and got few info using above mentioned command. But cannot exclude the desired dependency.

Comment: try remove the version on the artifactId, jersey-client-2.23.1 to jersey-client